# How do I get a Django Rest Framework DateTimeField to require timezone information?

Tags: django-rest-framework, rfc3339

I have a Django Rest Framework serializer with a DateTimeField. By default it will deserialize date/time values using the iso-8601 format. However, iso-8601 doesn't require a timezone offset. I need the user to always provide some timezone offset information (or better said, validate agains rfc 3339, a subset of iso-8601).

The field allows you to set a custom list of input_formats, but since Python is unable to parse rfc 3339 formatted dates correctly (i.e. an offset with a colon between the hour and minute part is unsupported) I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DateTimeField in Django Rest Framework is perfectly capable of parsing rfc 3339 datetime values thanks to it's use of [`django.utils.dateparse.parse_datetime`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.dateparse.parse_datetime) (it's somewhat more lenient, but that's fine).

`parse_datetime` either returns a timezone aware datetime instance (with tzinfo zet to a fixed offset) or a naive datetime instance (no tzinfo).

Django Rest Framework's DateTimeField converts any given value to an aware datetime value if `settings.USE_TZ` is set or the field was given a value for the `default_timezone` argument, otherwise any value is made naive.

The `enforce_timezone` method of DateTimeField is responsible for making values aware/naive.

Knowing this, enforcing that parsed values must be timezone aware can be achieved by overriding `enforce_timezone` and raising a `ValidationError` if the parsed datetime value is naive:

```
from django.utils import timezone

class DateTimeFieldWithOffset(serializers.DateTimeField):
    default_error_messages = {
        'naive': 'Datetime value is missing a timezone offset.'
    }

    def enforce_timezone(self, value):
        if timezone.is_naive(value):
            self.fail('naive')
        return super().enforce_timezone(value)
```